# ghostscript pdf/a conversion problem on ubuntu 18.10 and docker

Tags: docker, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript to convert pdf1.3 to pdf/a-1b using this command:

```
gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -sColorConversionStrategy=sRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf PDFA_def.ps input.pdf
```

The PDFA_def.ps is customized to use the srgb icc profile. Except that change it is the standard def file which comes with GS 9.26.

Now comes the tricky part:
1- running this conversion locally on a ubuntu 18.10, GS 9.26 it works fine an i get a valid pdf/a
2- running the same command in a docker container (ubuntu 18.10. GS 9.26) creates a pdf/a as well, which is considered to be valid

However, in the first scenario I can process the file using mustang (https://github.com/ZUGFeRD/mustangproject) to create a valid electronic invoice. In the second scenario (docker container) this fails, since the file is not considered to be valid pdf by mustang.

checking both pdf files I would have expected them to be identical since i am running the same converison on it. However they are not. The PDF create in the dockerfile is 10 bytes smaller and shows some different metainformation in the file itself.

I suspect that there must be some "hidden depdencies" that make GS to act different on my host system compared to a docker container, but it feels entirely wrong and I am running out of means to debug further.

Does anyone know, wether GS has some more depdencies that might cause the same command to produce different results?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'maybe'. It depends on how Ghostscript was built for starters.

I assume you are using a package, and not building from source yourself. In which case there are a number of dependencies including; FreeType, LibJPEG, JBIG2dec, LibTIFF, JPEG-XR, LCMS2, LibPNG, OpenJPEG, Expat, zlib, potentially IJS, CUPS and X-Windows, depending on what devices were built in.

Any or all of these could be system shared libraries instead of being built using the specific version shipped by Artifex. They could also be different versions on the two systems.

That said, I think its 'unlikely' that this is your problem. However, without seeing the PDF files I can't tell you why there is a difference. Differences in the metadata are to be expected, since that includes a date/time stamp.

I'd really need to see examples of the original and the two output PDF files to be able to comment further.

[Edit]

Looking at the files they have been produced compressed (unsurprisingly) which can obviously lead to differences in size if there are small differences in the input streams. So the first task was to decompress the files.

That done I see there are, essentially, no differences between them. One of the operating systems is using a time zone 7 hours behind UTC, the other is in UTC so where one of the systems is time stamping with (eg)

2019-04-26T19:49:01Z

The other is using

2019-04-26T12:51:35-07:00

So instead of Z (for UTC) you get -07:00 which is where the extra 10 bytes are coming from. Other than that, the Unique IDs are (as you would imagine) different, the Length values for the streams are different for the streams containing dates, and the startxref is different because the streams are different lengths.

Both files claim to be compatible with PDF/A-1b. In short I can see no real differences between them. Since you are using a tool to further process the files, I'd suggest you try taking the PDF file from your working system and try processing it on the non-working system, and vice versa, it seems to me that the problem may be the later processing rather than the PDF file itself. Perhaps you have different versions of that tool on the two systems.

For what it may be worth, Ghostscript can be induced into creating a ZUGFeRD file directly, see [this](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=696472) bug report and [this](http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commit;h=d4056b5dab63199d86c8fb140807b9b307a427c0) commit to the repository.

Comment: two files [incorrect](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxjxakd5necaswo/incorrect.pdf?dl=0) and [correct](https://www.dropbox.com/s/56al2jbpe7ikbl4/correct.pdf?dl=0). The correct one has been created using ghostscript on ubuntu 18.10, the incorrect one usig ghostscript in a ubuntu 18.10 docker container.

Comment: i suspect line 400-430 are possibly part of the problem, this is where i do see some differences in both version

Comment: I tried to create the zugferd invoice in all combinations: conversion on host system and docker and vice versa. Unfortunately all results point in the same direction: all files which have been converted in the docker container cannot be processed on any system. However, I cannot clearly state at that point if the validation of mustand might not even be the problem. If the validator is really picky and might be triggred by minor differences, this would explain the behaviour, acknowleding that there are per se differences in the pdf files after conversion on different systems

Comment: adding: the tool is the exact same version on both systems and the processing works only in the scenario where i actually did the converion on the host system